# Perl: fast sorting hash keys with positive and negative non-integer values

Tags: perl, sorting, hash, negative-number

I have a list of genes and scores and I want to sort the genes based on the scores. The list is huge (~42 million rows) and Perl *sort* function is too slow.

Using Sort::External module I can speed up the process but it sorts correctly only positive integers. Here is what I tried (I am showing just 10 cases):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Sort::External;

my %hash = (
    'gene1' => -19.86,
    'gene2' => -12.90,
    'gene3' => 4.07,
    'gene4' => 22.59,
    'gene5' => 55.43,
    'gene6' => 55.42,
    'gene7' => 9.89,
    'gene8' => 27.51,
    'gene9' => 6.43,
    'gene10' => 59.65
);

my @sortkeys;
while ( my ( $gene, $score ) = each %hash ) {
    push @sortkeys, ( pack( 'n', $score ) . $gene );
}
my $sortex = Sort::External->new( mem_threshold => 1024**2 * 8 );
$sortex->feed(@sortkeys);
$sortex->finish;
my @sorted;
while ( defined( $_ = $sortex->fetch ) ) {
    push @sorted, substr( $_, 2 );
}

foreach (@sorted){
    print join("\t",$_,$hash{$_}),"\n";
}
```

And here is the output:

```
gene3   4.07
gene9   6.43
gene7   9.89
gene4   22.59
gene8   27.51
gene5   55.43
gene6   55.42
gene10  59.65
gene1   -19.86
gene2   -12.9
```

What is the best solution for fast sorting hash keys with positive and negative non-integer values?

Comment: Why are you packing unsigned?

Comment: Database and table index are quite good at it.

Comment: Can you give an approximate notion of how big is 'huge'? We talking a million rows or a billion?

Comment: @stark, Doesn't matter. `pack('n', -100)`, `pack('S>', -100)` and `pack('s>', -100)` all produce the same result. `n` is the most familiar of these options.

Comment: @Sobrique ~42 million rows.

Answer (score 2):

If you had integers, you could handle negative integers using the following:

```
# Supports [32767, -32768]
pack( 'n', $score + 0x8000 )
```

But this considers 55.42 and 55.43 to be equal.

You'd use the same approach for floating point numbers.

1. Normalize the numbers into positive numbers.
2. Pads the numbers on the left so that the decimal point of all the numbers line up.

Most flexible:

```
# Supports ]67231, -32768], two decimal places.
sprintf( '%8.2f', $score + 0x8000 )
```

But you could also convert to an integer to produce shorter strings:

```
# Supports [327, -327], two decimal places.
pack( 'n', sprintf( '%.0f', $score * 100 ) + 0x8000 )

# Supports [21_474_836, -21_474_836], two decimal places.
pack( 'N', sprintf( '%.0f', $score * 100 ) + 0x8000_0000 )
```

(`sprintf '%.0f'` was used to round to the nearest integer, though it may not do this on all machines.)

Comment: assuming scores are -327.68..327.67, just multiply by 100 before packing.  if a bigger range and/or more precision is needed, switch to pack 'N'.  trying to make them strings with padding is going to take longer and produce larger data to be sorted.

Comment: FWIW in practice, sprintf rounds to nearest (usually using bankers' rounding) on every platform I am aware of, but in fact perl uses the C library, and even posix just says "The low-order digit shall be rounded in an implementation-defined manner."

Answer (score 1):

If relatively small integers are sufficiently precise to represent the floats, a simple bucket sort would do. Choosing `$scale` and `$offset` so that your min/max scores fall into a positive integer range:

```
my @buckets;
while(my ($gene, $score) = each %hash) {
    push @{$buckets[$score * $scale + $offset], $gene;
}
```

On my system, an array containing 2**20 empty arrayrefs eats 45 MB which shouldn't be too much overhead at this data set size.

Answer (score 0):

You could run two sorts, one for the negative numbers and one for the non-negative numbers.